# How to create table style with different column alignment

Tags: tables, cell

I'm trying to create a table style that would have some columns left aligned and some center aligned. Near as I can make out the table style options only allow for assigning cell styles to rows or to the first and last columns. But what If I want to apply a cell style to column other than the first or last. Or is there another way to do this?
What I'm going for is illustrated in the image below.

I should add that I'm styling an imported table. I understand that any styles that are not Table or Cell styles will be lost when the table is updated so I'd need a solution that uses only table or cell styles.

[image]

Comment: ermm.. Indesign??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a left-aligned cell style and a center-aligned cell style in InDesign, but the software will have no idea where to apply each. You need to decide which column uses which style and apply the styles manually per column group.

I understand you are importing the table content, but don't expect everything to auto-format with a single click, there is always some pushing to pulling needed. Especially if you update the table and import again, you will push and pull again on the formatting. InDesign does not remember what you did to the columns on the previous import.